# Where did Harvey Birdman get his law degree from?

Tags: harvey-birdman

At some point Harvey Birdman changed his career from being a freelance vigilante powered by the sun to being a high-powered attorney at the law firm of Sebben and Sebben... powered by the sun.

However, do we find out where Harvey acquired his law degree?

Comment: I can't look up the details right now, but one of the episodes points out that his degree is from the same place as Birdgirl, which I think is some sort of online or correspondence course.

Comment: *[It’s unclear whether he ever completed – or even attended – law school. He seemingly received his law degree from a three-hour correspondance course. In The Bird Girl of Guantanamole, he is quick to criticize Judy Ken Sebben, then disguised as Bird Girl...This is again referenced in the Harvey Birdman: Attorney At Law Volume 2 Boxset, the digipack case inside is made to look like a fake book written by Myron Reducto called " Reducto Guides-3 Hour Law School" with a picture of Harvey saying "I Got My Degree Over Lunch!!!"](http://harveybirdman.wikia.com/wiki/Harvey_Birdman)*

Comment: I'm going to downvote this on the grounds that it shows a *lack of research effort*. Although I know **nothing** about this universe, it took me less than 5 seconds to find a reasonable answer.

Comment: Don't we often criticize Wikia pages as not being good sources for answers, and require further (usually primary) sources to back them up?

Comment: Also, if you don't know the universe you really should look it up. Best legal/superhero TV show in history.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - That's not untrue but if you're unhappy with the Wikia answer, you should have at least seen it, mentioned it and indicated why you disregard it.

Comment: I'm the guy who asked the question, I looked at the page, but I don't own the DVDs, so can't verify it.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr  -Do you have any particular reason to doubt that the wikia is incorrect?

Comment: http://img.gamefaqs.net/box/1/8/8/85188_back.jpg - Note "Thanks Correspondence Course"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Harvey has a law degree.. probably. But the origins are unclear.

In season 3 episode 4, ["Bird Girl of Guantanamole"](http://harveybirdman.wikia.com/wiki/Bird_Girl_of_Guantanamole), Birdman tells Birdgirl to come back to his office when she has a law degree. She presents the following document to him:

[image: Birdgirl's Three Hour Diploma]

Immediately after, Peanut tries to take a closer look at Harvey's diploma hanging on the wall, but Harvey flips it over before he can. We get a brief look at it from a distance.

[image: Birdman's diploma on the wall]

It is laid out identically and the words "Three Hour Diploma" are legible, so we can assume it's from the same place that Birdgirl got hers.

Of course, it's questionable as to whether either of these is a *real* diploma. Here is the text from Birdgirl's diploma:

> **Three Hour Diploma**
>
> With the Concurrence of the Faculty has Awarded to
>
> **Birdgirl**
>
> The Degree of
>
> **A Lawyer**
>
> and hereby confers upon the candidate, all the rights and honors which everywhere pertain thereto. In testimony whereof, the Diploma has been signed under the seal of the Something or other. Probably.
>
> March 31, 1968.

As the diploma itself is uncertain as to whether it's valid, and no school name is present, it's certainly possible that the institution which issued it is not qualified or otherwise invalid.

The only remaining evidence is the seal in the bottom left of the diploma and the signatures of the school's President and Dean of Academic Affairs, but I was unable to tie these to anything. I expect that the signatures are jokes, or relatives of the show's creators. The seal may be completely made up or tied to something else in the Harvey Birdman universe.